# How to properly use ES6 Modules syntax in Typescript files (NextJS)?

Tags: typescript, next.js, package.json, es6-modules, react-typescript

The problem seems circular:

1. `package.json` does NOT have `type: "module"`. In this case I get this error when using modules in my typescript files:

```
An error occured while running the seed command:
/Users/me/code/me/prisma-learning/graphql-nextjs/prisma/seed.ts:1
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
^^^^^^
```

2. So I add `type: "module"` in `package.json` and this is now the error:

```
An error occured while running the seed command:
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for 
/Users/me/code/me/prisma-learning/graphql-nextjs/prisma/seed.ts
```

I just want to use ES6 modules in my TS files. The code is from an official Prisma boilerplate project:
https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/tree/latest/typescript/graphql-nextjs

Answer (score 3):

If you look in the **package.json** for this particual example, you'll see that they have a compiler option specified for ts-node:

```
    "ts-node": "ts-node --compiler-options \"{\\\"module\\\":\\\"commonjs\\\"}\"",
```

But for the "seed" command doesn't run it with this option.

So you can just replace:

```
"prisma": {
    "seed": "ts-node prisma/seed.ts"
  }
```

with

```
"prisma": {
    "seed": "npm run ts-node prisma/seed.ts"
  }
```

and then run `npx prisma db seed` as documented.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't configured your NextJs project to support typescript:

1. If you use `node seed.ts` to run seeder, You need to have `ts-node` package or compile this file to a regular JS file (using tsc or webpack)
2. If you use `seed.ts` file in a page or api of your project, check if you have a tsconfig.json file and typescript is installed as a dev dependency.

If none of them helps, please give more information about your project environments and configurations.